# How do I send desktop notifications using Python 3?

Tags: python, python3, notify-send

I have a python3.4 script.
I would like to send to the desktop a notification.
How do I handle this in python? Can I use notify-send?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

```py
#in my script
if something:
  notify-send 'Here is a notification !'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`notify-send`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/notify-send.1) as an external command:

```
import subprocess as s
s.call(['notify-send','foo','bar'])
```

Or you can use the [`notify2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/notify2) module (`sudo apt install python3-notify2`):

```
import notify2
notify2.init('foo')
n = notify2.Notification('foo', 'bar')
n.show()
```

There are more examples included in the package (see `/usr/share/doc/python3-notify2/examples/`).

Comment: @sgiri I thought the external lib would be better than subprocess. In either case you have to install something anyway.

Comment: @YdobEmos , `subprocess` is the standard library that is distributed with Python. Hence, no need to install it as a third party library. [ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html]

Comment: You have to install the packet supplying `notify-send`. Or at least on Kubuntu you have to. Maybe it's provided by default on Ubuntu, in that case it's indeed the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

No specific dependencies needed. These are wrappers around dbus anyway.

```py
import dbus

bus_name = "org.freedesktop.Notifications"
object_path = "/org/freedesktop/Notifications"
interface = bus_name

notify = dbus.Interface(dbus.SessionBus().get_object(bus_name, object_path), interface)
notify.Notify(ARGS)
```

For the args see the [specs](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/latest/ar01s09.html#commands).